# Junit5 Testing in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

How can I solve this error to successfully install Java Test Runner?

Error while installing 'Java Test Runner' extension. Please check the log for more details.
`command:workbench.action.showWindowLog`

Comment: Hi Austone. What does the log say?

Comment: Did you install the non-Microsoft published extension that may cause conflict?

Comment: Thanks for the concerns, the problem was solved with a manual installation though it took long